# SSL Certificate is invalid

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've purchased an SSL certificate from my domain's service provider and I've installed it on my VPS, however sometimes Google Chrome would give me the net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error and other times not. When attempting to use Postman to make the request to my server, I get an error saying that the certificate is expired. I've used sslhopper and it says my certificate has expired but I was issued the certificate a few days ago and is valid for the next year.
What could the problem be? I've searched high and low and none of the solutions I've come across work.

If it helps, I use Nginx as my proxy to my nodejs API.

Comment: I would guess this is another symptom of the Let's Encrypt R3 root expiration, but there's not enough detail in the question to know. The answer is usually to update your ca certificates on the device indicating the error.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I've used update-ca-certificates to generate a new ca-certificates.crt file and I've added that to my nginx sites-availabe default file. When I run nginx -t I get the error that the private key and certificate mismatch. I don't get the error when I only link the ca-certificate that I've received.